# Каждое новое предложение с заглавной буквы. Кириллица. PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день! С латиницей решается, а с русскими словами ну никак ((

```
 $str = "test one two one. three four <br> Предложение один.
 Предложение один. Предложение, два. Предложение три.";



echo preg_replace('/(^|[.!?]\s+)([a-zа-я])/ie',"'$1'.strtoupper('$2')",$str);
```

Comment: Попробуйте mb_strtoupper

Comment: так получаются все заглавные

Comment: видимо он имеет в виду не только mb_strtoupper но и модификатор юникода в регулярке `u` - `preg_replace('/(^|[.!?]\s+)([a-zа-я])/ieu',"'$1'.mb_strtoupper('$2')",$str);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте следующую функцию:

```
if(!function_exists('mb_ucfirst'))
{
    function mb_ucfirst($string, $enc = 'UTF-8')
    {
        return mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string, 0, 1, $enc), $enc) .
            mb_substr($string, 1, mb_strlen($string, $enc), $enc);
    }
}
function sentence_case($string) { 
    $sentences = preg_split('/([.?!]+)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); 
    $new_string = ''; 
    foreach ($sentences as $key => $sentence) { 
        $new_string .= ($key & 1) == 0? 
            mb_ucfirst(strtolower(trim($sentence))) : 
            $sentence.' '; 
    } 
    return trim($new_string); 
} 

print sentence_case('HMM. WOW! WHAT?'); 

// Outputs: "Hmm. Wow! What?"
```

Comment: В английской раскладке - да. Кириллица - не получается! (((

Comment: Попробуйте теперь, код обновил

Comment: а сейчас каждое новое слово с заглавной. Как кириллица, так и латиница

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan, каждое слово у вас с большой буквы, а не предложение.

Comment: Действительно, вот теперь у меня всё нормально отображает, проверяйте

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий пример http://ideone.com/jpQb9k

> Добавляем модификатор юникода в регулярку `u`.
>   Используем [mb_strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strtoupper.php) вместо strtoupper().

```
$str = "test one two one. three four <br> Предложение один.
 предложение один. предложение, два. предложение три.";

echo preg_replace('/(^|[.!?]\s+)([a-zа-я])/ieu',"'$1'.mb_strtoupper('$2')",$str);
//Test one two one. Three four <br>
//Предложение один. Предложение один. Предложение, два. Предложение три.
```

Comment: Ух ты `<b>Warning</b>:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>9</b><br />`

Comment: @Visman первокод я не трогал, в зависимости от версий пыхи код пашет, как и видно на ideone

Comment: Обновите свою версию php. Модификатор `/e` был удалёт из php из-за проблем с безопасностью. Весто этого рекомендуется использовать [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: @Arnial вы это не мне говорите.

Answer (score 0):

Старовата версия пхп, если `/e` еще работает. Добавь `u` флаг в модификаторы, должно заработать, во всяком случае, в тестере все работает.